# unable to fetch logo in joomla using $this->params->get('logo')

Tags: php, joomla

I am creating new theme using joomla. I have uploaded the logo in admin and trying to show the uploaded image using $this->params->get('logo')

But it is not working

In my **templateDetails.xml** I have added

```
<config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="advanced">
                <field name="logo" type="media" label="TPL_SOFT_FIELD_LOGO_LABEL" description="TPL_SOFT_FIELD_LOGO_DESC" />
                <field name="banner" type="media" label="TPL_SOFT_FIELD_BANNER_IMAGE_LABEL" description="TPL_SOFT_BANNER_IMAGE_DESC" />
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
```

In **index.php** I have added two lines

```
echo $this->params->get('logo');
echo $headerImage    = $this->params->get('banner');
```

These two line returns nothing. Whats wrong with my code.

**Update - 1**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 9
    [home] => 0
    [template] => soft
    [params] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
        (
            [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [logo] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get parameters from the template, you must firstly include this line at the top of your **index.php** file:

```
$params = JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(true)->params;
```

otherwise `$this` will not return anything.

Hope this helps

Comment: Added as you mentioned and called like this `$params->get('logo');` then too no result. Any other possibilities?

Comment: I saw the array structure it returns empty logo array. Check my updated question

Comment: Try going back to what you were originally using >> `$this->params->get('logo');`

Comment: I could not understand why array is empty can you?

Comment: array? which array are you referring to?